# quartz debug logging in console not stopping

Tags: logging, log4j, quartz-scheduler, slf4j

following is my property file.

```
log = ${catalina.home}/logs/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF

# Define the file appender

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=${log}/DellwebApp.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd


# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.conversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

i tried almost every solution in stackoverflow. still i am not able to get rid of this issue.
Please suggest sollutions.

Answer (score 0):

A few details are missing from your question so the assumptions are

1. This log4j properties file is actually getting used
2. You have correctly setup SLF4J (you include it in your tags)
3. Quartz lib has namespace `org.quartz` (otherwise replace this)

The solution is to tell log4j to only report only say **ERROR** level stuff logged in the library. For that add this extra line in your log4j props file:

```
org.quartz = ERROR
```